# MySQL - how to use extended properties?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've been working for a while with SQL Server and I used **Extended Properties** to tag databases, for example - to save the name of the main DB user (for private use).

Now, I need to start using MySQL.

The thing is that the concept of Extended Properties doesn't seem to exist in MySQL Workbench. Is there an equivalent? If not, what do you recommend in order to compensate for the lack of this feature?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Document this stuff elsewhere, like source control. I've always questioned the value of extended properties as documentation, since if you lose the database, you also lose the documentation. If you stored the documentation separately, and you lose the database, you have a chance at being able to rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no extended properties in MySQL.
If you want to add comments to objects, you can do it. Some objects support them.

If you need more, then you should think about your database logic/schema, where to store these information.